# How do i place image in android toolbar?

Tags: android, xml, responsive-design

how do I design profile picture like in this image in android? I tried placing it in the toolbar it won't show half below the toolbar.

[image: toolbar image]

Here is a look at the code I am trying. I am using a linear layout at top and then again a linear layout for holding logo and text and the image is at the bottom in root linear layout. Despite setting margin-top it still there and not moving to location:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:menu="@menu/action_menu"
    android:background="@color/colorPink1"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    app:collapseIcon="@drawable/logo_mini"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:minHeight="0dp">
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="top"
               android:orientation="vertical" android:gravity="end" android:dividerPadding="100dp">
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/main_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:padding="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:gravity="center">
        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/center_icon"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo_mini"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            />

        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/bar"
                android:src="@drawable/bar"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="Hi ,"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/emp_name" android:textSize="30sp"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="Wellcome back,"
                android:visibility="gone"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView5"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="here ae you assigned sites"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:elevation="10dp"

        android:src="@drawable/user_photo"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/center_icon"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:gravity='center'
        android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: use margin-top as a minus value like -50dp

Comment: already tried no effects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `CoordinatorLayout` and  `layout_anchor` ,`layout_anchorGravity` attributes for the `ImageView` to locate the image on the edge of the toolbar

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        app:collapseIcon="@drawable/logo_mini">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:dividerPadding="100dp"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="50dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/center_icon"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0"
                        android:src="@drawable/logo_mini" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/bar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:src="@mipmap/mic" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/emp_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Hi ,"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"

                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Wellcome back,"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="here ae you assigned sites"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dim150"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dim150"
            android:layout_below="@+id/home_txt"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dim20"
            android:src="@drawable/user_photo"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/toolbar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change your layout like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    app:collapseIcon="@drawable/logo_mini">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:dividerPadding="100dp"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/center_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo_mini" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:src="@mipmap/mic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/emp_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hi ,"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Wellcome back,"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="here ae you assigned sites"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="72dp"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:gravity='center'
    android:src="@drawable/user_photo" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Constraint Layout to make responsive UI

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context=".StartActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" /></android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```